# Hard drive reports 80 GB instead of advertised 500 GB

Tags: linux, hard-drive

I was trying out different Linux distros when I noticed the problem. The distros I tested were:

- Ubuntu MATE
- Linux Mint Cinnamon
- Linux Mint XFCE

I noticed the problem while I was testing this last one.

Here is the output of `parted -l`:

```
Model: ATA WDC WD800BEVS-07 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 80.0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  80.0GB  80.0GB  primary  fat32


Warning: The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but
Linux says it is 512 bytes.
Ignore/Cancel? i                                                          
Model: IS817 innostor (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 32.2GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 2048B/512B
Partition Table: mac
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name   Flags
 1      2048B   6143B   4096B                Apple
 2      1695MB  1698MB  2425kB               EFI


Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0
has been opened read-only.
Error: /dev/sr0: unrecognised disk label
Model: Slimtype DVD A DA8A5SH (scsi)                                      
Disk /dev/sr0: 653MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 2048B/2048B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

The problem is with `/dev/sda`. I noticed the warning about the block size and tried the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/675649/unable-to-delete-usb-drive-partitions-block-size-error). Basically it instructs to write the first blocks of the disk as 2048 bytes blocks, like so:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=2048 count=32
```

That didn't solve anything as `parted -l` still issues the same warning and the drive capacity is still wrong.

What else can I try to fix this issue?

Comment: The model number for the drive seems to line up with it being an 80GB drive: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=WD800BEVS-07

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/781236/201079 seems to list a very different set of fixes

Comment: @Mokubai

The model number is very strange. My laptop is an Asus X550C which comes with 500 GB hard drive.

Comment: @Mokubai I also tried those steps. No success.

Comment: I just noticed that USB stick (/dev/sdb) capacity is also wrong. It should be 8 GB.

Comment: I would have some very pointed questions to the place where you bought the laptop and memory stick from.  I wouldn't expect `parted` to be lying about this.

Comment: @Mokubai I was about to say the same. Open the bottom of the laptop and take a very good look at the label on the harddrive. If Linux says it is a 80GB WD800BEVEVS-07 it is usually right. The USB stick being messed up could be because it is apparently partitioned in a Mac using a GPT partition table. That might throw other operatings systems a bit off (It is very unusual for a 8 GB stick to have a GPT table. Only MacOS defaults to GPT.)

Comment: Blocksize message refers to the USB stick. NOT to the internal hardrive.

Answer (score 2):

The HDD is from  the manufacter Western Digital,model (WD800BEVS) which has a capacity of 80gb.

I would recommend you to check the S/N of the HDD on the website of the manufacter and check the oficial info.